# Access select query for combo box not always evaluating checkbox value

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a form with a combo box & a checkbox (chkClosed). For the combo box I have put the row source as a select query. It has two fields (both from Table1): Field1, Field2 *(not shown)* & its criteria is `[Forms]!Form1]![chkClosed]`

Table1 example data:

```
Field1    Field2
Test      -1
Test1      0
Test2      0
Test3     -1
```

Problem is that when I uncheck chkClosed at runtime the dropdown list doesn't change. I know its evaluating it correctly though as if I switch to design then back to form view while its checked it shows Test & Test3 in dropdown list & vice versa. Just time it evaluates it is at startup rather than constantly, I am sure I will have to change something with events. This is just an example, the data I am doing is actually from a SQL source, but the logic still applies I just use criteria: `IIf([Forms]![Form1]![chkClosed]=-1,1,0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to requery the combo box to update the row source.  In the checkbox's AfterUpdate event, add the following line:

```
Private Sub chkClosed_AfterUpdate()
    Me.Combo1.Requery
End Sub
```

Comment: Indeed that solved my issue, however I am not understanding why exactly? Does the row source only get compiled on form startup?

Comment: Sort of.  In order for Access to know it has to requery the control source whenever your checkbox value changes, it would have to build a dependency tree (similar to what Excel does in deciding when functions need to be recalculated).  This would add an enormous amount of complexity and it still might not be what you want.  Imagine that your row source query took 30 seconds to execute.  You might decide that you don't want that to happen when a user checks or unchecks that other box.  Access lets the developer make that decision; a wise choice in my view.

Comment: So when does it normally compile that list?

Comment: When the form opens.  When you explicitly call the .Requery method of the control.  I think that's it.